# Are Windows-10 wbengine backup VHDX files updated with the latest changes since the backup finished, if the VHDX file is left mounted?

Tags: windows-10, backup, vhdx, windows-system-image

I have a Windows 10 system-image VHDX backup file from 1am, which is a backup of the C: drive  (Labeled OS).  The VHDX backup file is on drive J:

Long after the backup has finished, I go to "disk management" and attach the J:vhdx file as **"read only"**.

I mount the J:VHDX file as drive X:

Disk Management shows like this: [Image of the X: drive in disk management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVkFw.png)

I go to a test TXT file on C: and change the file.   Note: This file was present before the 1am backup.

I open the same file **on X:** and it's changed there too!   AND,  the date-time stamp of the J:VHDX file has changed from 2:44 am (when the backup finished) to now showing 2:05 pm (when I changed and saved the test TXT file on C:).

This means the change on C: was written to the backup J:VHDX file "through" the "read-only" X: drive mount !!!

The same result will happen with the backup disk OFF.  (Altho, delayed of course).

I unmount the X: drive, and turn off the backup disk (where the J:VHDX file is).

I again change the text TXT file.

I create a new TXT file.

I turn on the backup disk.

I mount the J:VHDX file as X:.  And...

The changes shows up on the X: drive test TXT file, and the new file is present on the X: drive.  And the J:VHDX time stamp is changed again.

So, does this mean ALL changes done to C: will be propagated to its backup if it happens to be mounted?

Are full backups then necessary nightly?  Perhaps instead, just leave the VHDX mounted; it would be like a real time incremental backup!

Is there a way to "disassociate" the backup VHDX file so the auto-backup feature won't take place?

I can't find anything on google describing this behavior, but it's probably because I don't know what the feature is called.   Can somebody tell me what this feature is?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I'm an idiot!

The testing file was down a directory path that had a link that pointed to the physical C: drive.   So, the X: drive had the link that was pointing to C:

So, both files WERE on the C: drive.